# Performance question about enumerating empty lists

Tags: c#

which is better, performance-wise, when you potentially have an empty list?

```
if (_myList != null && _myList.Count > 0)
{
  foreach (thing t in _myList )
  {
    ...
```

or without checking if _myList count contains anything:

```
if (_myList != null)
{
  foreach (thing t in _myList )
  {
   ...
```

I'm guessing there's probably not much in it, but that the first one is *slightly* quicker (?)

Thanks

---

edit:

To clarify, I mean a list like this: `List<Thing>`

Comment: I bet that when you have an empty list, performance does not matter.

Comment: If there's currently no semantic difference between a `null` and an empty list, you might want to consider moving to always using empty lists to convey that meaning. It will make your code much neater to not have to worry about null references all the time...

Comment: Have you measured this and found this to actually be a matter for discussion? if not, go measure: and then fix the things that *do* matter. I very much doubt this is one of them. Otherwise you are giving yourself that warm cosy feeling of having improved something, without actually benefiting the overall system **at all**.

Comment: Imagine that you have a performance problem with the enumeration of empty lists (<insert your own highly-contrived-unrealistic-and-insane scenario here>). Now imagine what happens when the lists are not empty. Carefully, because your head might just explode.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It's a fair cop that it's probably not worth worrying about - it's just one of those things that has bugged by from time to time.  Out of interest, how do you measure something like this?

Comment: @adrianos - for something simple like this, use the StopWatch class, and call the code thousands of times in a tight loop.  Then divide the elapsed time by the number of times you called the code.

Comment: @Will: No need to divide. You can do an analysis on the full iteration numbers if you run both scenarios the same number of times.

Comment: @Martinho - Thanks for the advice on scalar multiplication... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one way to answer a performance question:

1. **Measure**
2. **Measure**
3. **Measure**

The only way you can know if:

- I can improve the code
- I *have* improved the code
- And most importantly: **What code to improve first**

is to measure how much time different parts of the program is taking, and then improving the top items first.

To answer your question, I would assume that the miniscule overhead of a few extra objects is indeed going to cost you some cycles compared to just calling Count (assuming that is a fast call, field read for instance).

However, since you're asking this question it tells me that you don't have enough information about the state of your program and your code, so the chance of improving that miniscule overhead actually having a noticable effect for your users is so slim I wouldn't bother.

I can guarantee you have bigger fish to fry performance-wise, so tackle those first.

Personally I don't use `null` references except when dealing with databases or in a few lines of code to signal "not initialized yet", other than that I use empty lists and strings, etc. Your code is much easier to read and understand, and the benefit of microoptimization on this level will never be noticed.

Comment: "There is only one way to answer a *bad* question about performance". I think there are good performance questions, but unfortunately they are rare and far between :(

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are calling your code in a tight loop, the difference will be insignificant. However, be advised that there is a difference: the check for `_myList.Count > 0`  avoids the calling of `GetEnumerator`, the creation of an IEnumerator implementing object (a heap allocation) and a call to that enumerator's `MoveNext()` method.

If you are in a tight spot performance-wise that avoided (heap allocation + virtual method calls) might help, but in general your code is shorter and easier to understand by avoiding the explicit on `_myList.Count`.

Comment: If you are in that tight spot, the solution is not a check for List.Count. What happens if the lists are not empty? The performance considerations vanish?

Comment: If you are having to check the emptyness of the lists in a very tight loop, and the lists are normally empty, then yes, there is a performance benefit. However, if you are spinning in a tight loop checking for the emptyness of lists, you're probably polling (which is considered evil) and should consider changing to a more event-driven design.

Answer (score 1):

Compulsory Disclaimer: You should have already identified this as a problem area via profiling before attempting to "optimise it", and hence you'll already have a the tools at hand to determine quickly and easily which methods faster. Odds are, neither will make an appreciable difference to your application's performance.

But that being said, Count, for System.Generics.Collection.List<> will almost definitely be quicker.

Although optimisation improves things **greatly** (don't be scared of using `foreach`! it's nearly free), `foreach` more or less involves:

```
var enumerator = _myList.GetEnumerator();
try
{
  while (enumerator.MoveNext())
  {
  }
}
finally
{
  enumerator.Dispose();
}
```

which is a lot more complicated than merely comparing a simple property (safe assumption that List.Count is a simple property) with a constant.